# Remote console on a webbrowser to access to heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Is it possible to have a console on a web browser to access to heroku?

I want to access quickly to the console for urgencies even if I don't have any special program installed (like a terminal or ssh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding [the web-console](https://github.com/rails/web-console) gem and configuring it.  I've never tried it with Heroku, but it should work.

This likely goes without saying, but I strongly recommend you have some form of authentication and/or authorization in front of this, as it is direct access to the backend of your Heroku environment.